# Temp directory space issue

Tags: linux

i am facing an issue, i am trying to import a table data into SPSS Statistics server, but due to space constraints in the ‘temp’ directory location i am not able to facilitate the data import.I need to either increase the temp directory size or change the temp directory location thereby having sufficient space for SPSS processing.How can i change the location of ‘Temp’ directory to a desired location in the server without changing any configuration file settings.

Comment: what space constraints are you talking about?

Comment: More information regarding the current layout WRT filesystems/logical volumes/disks is needed to provide an answer. Please add to your question the output of the following commands: `fdisk -l`, `df -h`, `cat /etc/fstab`, `df -h`.

Comment: the file i am importing is very huge. and the application says it is unable to import this file due to space constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily bind-mount some other directory from a filesystem with sufficient space over your temp directory:

```
mkdir /home/user/tmp
mount -o bind /home/user/tmp /path/to/temp
```

Comment: what if there's only one big / filesystem?

Comment: If there's not enough space on the only filesystem, there won't be enough space for the temp directory anyway. The question only makes sense if the temp directory is on a different filesystem.

Comment: The question needs additional info, indeed